# How can I get a jQuery scroll function to fire with a quick scroll?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to keep a yellow box "pinned in place" as a container div scrolls up and down the page, but then ride with the container off screen, both up and down. This works for a slow scroll, but not for a fast scroll. Is there anything I can do to my code to ensure that it fires faster, or to make the screen scroll more slowly?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="purple"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
margin-top:500px;
margin-bottom:500px;
height:1000px;
width:600px;
background-color:blue;
position:relative;
}

#purple{
height:10px;
width:10px;
background-color:purple;
position:absolute;
margin-right:50px;
}
#green{
height:10px;
width:10px;
background-color:green;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
#yellow{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
margin-top:50px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
var distance = $('#purple').offset().top;
var distance2 = $('#green').offset().top;
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
       $("#yellow").css("position","fixed");
       $("#yellow").css("margin-left",'8px');
       $("#yellow").css("top",'0px');
 }

 if (( $window.scrollTop() - distance <= 15 )&& ($window.scrollTop() >= distance2 - 1000 )) {
       $("#yellow").css("position","absolute");
       $("#yellow").css("top","15px");
       $("#yellow").css("margin-left",'0px');
       $("#yellow").css("bottom","auto");

  }

   if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance2 - 180  ) {
       $("#yellow").css("position","absolute");
       $("#yellow").css("top","auto");
       $("#yellow").css("margin-left",'0px');
       $("#yellow").css("bottom",'40px');

  }
  });
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7nfyu4ys/1/

Is it my code, or does jQuery just act like this sometimes??

Comment: Uh, solved it. It didn't need my && clause. Ignore...

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you did not, but I did a sample anyhow (-; Please see:

https://jsfiddle.net/jjkhgv18/

```js
var distance = $("#purple").offset().top; //above yellow
var distance2 = $("#green").offset().top + $("#green").height(); //below yellow
var height = $("#yellow").height();
var margin = $("#yellow").css("top"); //space to give from top of purple and bottom of green
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function(e) {
 if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance2 - height - parseInt(margin,10)*2) {
  $("#yellow").css({"position":"absolute", "top":"auto", "bottom":margin, "left":"0"});
 } else if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
  $("#yellow").css({"position":"fixed", "top":margin, "left":$("body").css("margin-left")});
 } else {
  $("#yellow").css({"position":"absolute", "top":margin, "bottom":"auto", "left":"0"});
 }
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 1500px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#purple {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
}

#green {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#yellow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="purple"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

The issue was mostly about the manual calculations - your first and third if's are valid, but really the middle one is default - but the second you are running into cases where none of the three are true so the css is never reset. I reorganized the if statements and it seems to work now. Formatting-wise I just went for single css functions and more automated values, plus removed the margin settings and just used top for #yellow.